# Can two blocks be executed in the same warp?

Tags: cuda

From the CUDA C programming guide:

> The threads of a thread block execute concurrently on one
>   multiprocessor, and **multiple thread blocks can execute concurrently on
>   one multiprocessor**. As thread blocks terminate, new blocks are
>   launched on the vacated multiprocessors.

Now, say I have many (e.g. 1000) blocks of few threads each (e.g. 4), and each thread uses few registers so that multiple threads could be run together.

I would like to understand if, given a warp of e.g. 32 threads, 8 blocks will actually run together to fill the warp, or if this will not happen.

After reading the above quotation, my guess is that this *may* happen if the instructions to be executed are the same for all the threads in the warp regardless the blocks in which the threads are (in this case, 32 threads from 8 blocks which happen to have the same program counter).

But maybe I am totally wrong. So I would like to better understand what happen if block size is smaller than warp size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not happen.  The threads in a warp always come from the same block.

From the programming guide, on the assembly of [threads into warps](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture):

> The way a block is partitioned into warps is always the same; each warp contains threads of consecutive, increasing thread IDs with the first warp containing thread 0. Thread Hierarchy describes how thread IDs relate to thread indices in the block.

Answer (score 2):

Each warp is exclusive to a certain threadblock so, in your example, if you have a threadblock with 8 thread, then resources for a whole warp (32 threads) will be allocated and whole warp will be executed; the only difference is that only the first 8 threads will be allowed to make writes, the rest of the threads will be masked out.
Sharing of a warp between multiple threadblocks is not possible.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @AkiRoss not off the top of my head. A good place to start is the ocupancy calculator included in the CUDA Toolkit. You can experiment with the "threads per block" value and you will see that from 1 up until 32 nothing will change... there is a certain granularity when allocating resources on a gpu. You can find more details in the "GPU Data" sheet in the occupany calculator.

Comment: @AkiRoss also the term "Thread" is not a particularly good name for what it really is. In reality, the SM works with warps and not with "threads". Warp is basically executed in a SIMD fashion with a width of 32 (plus some extra handling of divergence). "Thread" is just a name to describe one of those 32 pieces in SIMD.

Comment: Yes, I was aware about warp execution over the cores, SIMD and SIMT architectures, but I was not sure about this possibility. Thanks for the suggestions.